# Close Window Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way i can create a javascript which will run the command `onClick="my_onclick()"` if they close the browser window? If so can you also make a popup that warns them If they close the window it will log out on the same script?

I am trying some variations of what i found but its not working for me.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(window).bind("beforeunload", function() { 
        return confirm("If you confirm, you will be logged off the internet."); 
    });
});
```

I need it to return these paramters.

```
 function my_onclick()
     {URL = "http://%SERVERIP%/logout?%PARAMS%"; window.location.href=URL;}
```

Comment: Well that is not how `beforeunload` is used... there should not be a confirm in it. And no, there is no way to force the page to do an action when the browser closes.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/beforeunload

Comment: So how do i have it send the function on confirm?

Comment: @sonicboom, you can't do this. You cannot set the `window.location` after the page has closed.

Comment: No basically i want the user to try to close the window, if he confirms it, it will send this function `' function my_onclick()
     {URL = "http://%SERVERIP%/logout?%PARAMS%"; window.location.href=URL;}'`

Answer (score 1):

The only 'event' available within Javascript that relates to the closing of a window is `onbeforeunload`, which expects to return a boolean (from the result of calling `window.confirm()`.

It cannot be used to pass data back, since the page will already have expired. In short, no you can't do that.

Comment: There is no way to pass data back before the closing of the window confirms?

Comment: Is there a way to pass data back when he presses Exit, and then he gets a message saying hes been logged out and it confirms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**window.onbeforeunload**](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), here's an example of what you need:

```
window.onbeforeunload = myConfirm;

function myConfirm(){
    confirmMessage="If you confirm, you will be logged off !!";
    return confirmMessage;
}
```

Comment: Can i have it return this on confirm? `function my_onclick()
     {URL = "http://%SERVERIP%/logout?%PARAMS%"; window.location.href=URL;}`

Comment: No I don't think you can, because the window will be closed anyway.